# How to upload file from inside a modal window using selenium webdriver (python)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Inside the web application i'm developing, we have an option that let's the user import a .csv file. So, i was trying to test this feature, but everytime i tried to click on the 'import' button, selenium gave me the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (873, 24). Other element would receive the click: ...
>     (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513 (2c63aa53b2c658de596ed550eb5267ec5967b351),platform=Linux 4.10.0-37-generic x86_64)

This is the process selenium goes through until it crashes: It clicks on the import button, and opens up the import employees window. But, it stops there, because it can't click on the select button to open the upload window.

[image: selecting the import button]

[image: modal window that appears]

Basically what i wan't to know is how to click on the 'select' button with selenium webdriver, so that i can import a .csv file into the application.

Comment: Clicking the select button will not help you, chrome opens an OS dialog to browse and select the file, the browser does not have control over this dialog and thus you will not be able to select a file. The only way possible to upload files with selenium is to type the full path in the textbox `element.send_keys(path)`

Comment: The problem is that this web application has no textbox

Comment: where it says `Select a file .csv`, does it shows the file path upon selection? if so that's a textbox, if not is probably hidden but very unlikely

Comment: no, it serves as a queue for all the other files you selected for upload, similar to dropbox

Comment: This is as far as I can help without a snippet of the HTML, one thing I'm positive about is the file name is posted to a text field, theres no other way to submit a file, you just have to find the form field that holds the file name and modify it directly.

Comment: OK. I'll try to find the textbox

Comment: I was mistaken, it's not a text field, is an `<input type='file'>` element, you still type in it with `send_keys()`